# vsftpd: login as one user, work as another

Tags: vsftpd

The local user `wcsadmin` has default umask and can create files and, what's more important, directories in a shared folder `/ftp`. The new directory `/ftp/test` has owner `wcsadmin` and permissions `drwxr-xr-x`.

I need to setup `vsftp` so the clients login as `ftpuser` and can delete files inside `/ftp/test`. Only `root` or `wcsadmin` can delete files there.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

vsftpd.conf:

```
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user_conf
```

/etc/vsftpd/user_conf/ftpuser:

```
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=wcsadmin
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
```